# Does android app has permissions to change profile

Tags: android

I am not an android developer so this may sound very novice..

How does permissions/ access to actions or data takes place in Android?
My specific requirement is:

1. To able to change profiles (ex: General to silent) from the app
2. Able to access call log details! Not exactly calls but when a call is coming, when user is picking up etc... when the mobile is in silent..

So, can andriod api provide these kind of information?

Answer (score 1):

1. AudioManager, [setRingerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29)
2. you can use a BroadcastReceiver to catch those kind of events. For instance [CALL_STATE_RINGING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_RINGING)